# How do you whitelist folders of apps created by unidentified developers? on ventura 13.3.1

Tags: terminal, settings, ventura, documentation

i know `--master-disable` is an option, but is there a way to instead just whitelist a specific folder? currently I'm having to manually ctrl-click every .lib individually to run an app successfully. I tried finding documentation for spctl but i couldn't find any that were up to date